# Representation finite Hopf algebras up to stable equivalence

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, hopf-algebras

It is well known that every representation-finite group algebra $KG$ is stable equivalent to a symmetric Nakayama algebra.

> Question: Is it true that every representation-finite Hopf algebra is stable equivalent to a selfinjective Nakayama algebra?

(here all algebras are assumed to be finite dimensional over a field)